# Call codeigniter hooks after pre_controller and before post_controller

Tags: php, hook, codeigniter-3

I want to validate request based on input post parameter. if using pre_controller not able to get post value. if post_controller used controller executed first and showing me validation error. I want to validate every request so do not want to manually write code in controller after post parameters.
following is code,
file: hooks.php

```
$hook['post_controller'][] = array(
    'class'    => 'Validate',
    'function' => 'society',
    'filename' => 'hooks.validate.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks',
    'params'   => array()
);
```

file: hooks.validate.php

```
function society(){     

        $CI = & get_instance();
        if($CI->is_hookable) {
            $method = $CI->input->method();
            $society_id = "";
            if($method == 'get' || $method == 'GET')
            {
                $society_id = $CI->get('society_id');
            }
            if($method == 'post' || $method == 'POST')
            {
                $society_id = $CI->post('society_id');
            }
            if($society_id!="")
            {
                if(!is_society_exists($society_id))
                {
                    $response['message'] = "Invalid or inactive society";
                    $response['status'] = false;
                    $CI->response($response, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $response['message'] = "Unkown request";
                $response['status'] = false;
                $CI->response($response, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: try with `post_controller_constructor` ;

Answer (score 0):

The hook you want is "post_controller_constructor" which happens after the controller is created but before it is executed.

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'][] = array(
    'class'    => 'Validate',
    'function' => 'society',
    'filename' => 'hooks.validate.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks',
    'params'   => array()
);
```

Here's a more concise bit of code that (I think) gets the job done.

```
function society()
{
    $CI = & get_instance();
    if($CI->is_hookable)
    {
        //both input::post('item') and input::get('item') 
        //return NULL if the item is not found
        //you don't need the following because NULL is empty too
        //$society_id = "";

        $method = $CI->input->method();
        //use the variable as the method to call
        $society_id = $CI->input->$method('society_id');

        if( ! empty($society_id))
        {
            if( ! is_society_exists($society_id))
            {
                $response['message'] = "Invalid or inactive society";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $response['message'] = "Unkown request";
        }
        $response['status'] = false;
        $CI->response($response, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
    }
}
```

The line

```
$society_id = $CI->input->$method('society_id');
```

will call either `$CI->input->get('society_id')` or `$CI->input->post('society_id')` depending on what `$CI->input->method()` returns without the need for a bunch of `if/else` code.